# What is the runtime complexity of this print_star functions?

Tags: c++, time-complexity

I have this printing star for integer num function that works for positive integers:

```
void print_stars(int num)
{
    if (num < 0)
        print_stars(num + 1);
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = num; j > 0; --j)
                cout << "*";
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

That print num * num stars in the console.
For example, if given integer is 3, it prints:

```
***
***
***
```

Given that the integer is positive, what is the runtime complexity?
I assume that it is O(num^2) because it just go through num times in each iteration.

Edit: Sorry for the typo, I meant O(num^2) because there are num visiting for each of num iteration. Thank you!

Comment: O(num²), you answered it in your example, but the assumption is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

O(n^2) where n is the number inputted.

This is because there are two for loops, each running n times. So, n*n = n^2 and the running time is O(n^2). The other operations are lower order terms.

Keep in mind that O(n) would not be possible because n could be negative. If the code was linear time, it would be O(abs(n))